# Request data to global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, request

How to put data in global variable?

```
const request = require("request");

let req = `empty`;

(async () => {
    req = await request("http://www.stackoverflow.com", function(error, response, data) {
        //console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
})();

console.log(req);
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
global.globalString = "This can be accessed anywhere!";  
console.log(globalString);
```